# popBackStack() after saveInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm running into an issue where I have an Activity with multiple fragments. For any individual fragment, you can perform a search operation, which works just fine...if you search from any of the fragments, it will display a new Activity to handle the searching, then return the result to the Activity to handle displaying a new fragment. The problem is, after a search operation, I want to be able to clear (almost) all the fragments away using `popBackStackImmediate(...)` and since `saveInstanceState(...)` was called, I get an exception that says:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"
```

Any idea how to pop from the back stack after `onSaveInstanceState` has been called?

Answer (score 22):

Apparently my issue spawned from the call being made in onActivityResult(...)

I was able to fix the issue by putting the UI modification code inside a Runnable, then posting the Runnable to the main thread:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // UI code here
    }
};
Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(r);
```

Comment: Man you just saved my mind. I almost gone crazy trying to figure out whats wrong. +1

Comment: Fixed the problem I was having! SingleTop activity, popping fragment backstack in onNewIntent. adding @UiThread to my method with AndroidAnnotations fixed the crash.

Comment: call super.onActivityResult first before your logic and the issue will get fixed as FragmentActivity's onActivityresult calls mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();

Comment: Thanks bro you just made my day. I was stuck in this for decades.

Answer (score 18):

call `super.onActivityResult` first before your logic and the issue will get fixed as FragmentActivity's `onActivityResult` calls `mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();`

Answer (score 6):

This answer is may help to someone. When your activity is not visible, you unable to call popBackStackImmediate(...)  it will throw **illegal Exception: can not perform this action after onsaveinstancestate.**

Instead of that you can check, Is the activity is visible or not? before call the popBackStackImmediate().

If your activity is not visible, don't call popBackStackImmediate. **Through the boolean flag you can achieve, when activity opens again**.

Ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Below flag used to check activity visible or not?
private boolean isActivityVisible;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isActivityVisible = true;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isActivityVisible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't understand the last part. So if my activity is not visible, and I don't do the operation, how will I know I should do it once the activity is visible?

Comment: If you want to call popBackStackImmediate(...), when your activity is not visible. Set a boolean to true. 

When your activity come to foreground, in activity onResume() you can check the boolean, if it is true, then you can call popBackStackImmediate(...)

Comment: How exactly? Can you edit your answer with a code example?

Comment: This should be the correct answer if a peace of code was included!

Comment: @YonatanNir It seems sometimes activity go to foreground and available to user's actions before onResume is called. So this crash happens.

Answer (score 1):

What about popping the stack immediately before starting your associated activity?  onSaveInstanceState wouldn't be called until startActivity was called (and the new activity came in front of the current one0... immediately before that, pop the fragment stack back to your desired state and then call startActivity.

Since the fragment stack is a layer over the normal task/back stack, I think that modifying it "from the middle" would cause issues and that's why you're seeing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me is to check if fragment manger doesn't hava a saved state

`if (fragmentManager != null && !fragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
       fragmentManager.popBackStack();
  }`

Answer (score -5):

Or just put it in a try-catch:

```
try {
  getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // ignore
}
```

This is basically the same as `commitAllowingStateloss()` except we don't have a `popBackStackAllowingStateloss()`.

In most cases I get an error even though I don't need to save state.