# Illegal state exception in popBackStack

Tags: android

In my application I'm using BottomBar Menu's. When quickly selecting menu's I'm getting following crash report on crashlytics(only in some devices).  Here is the **stacktrace**

> Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform
>   this action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:781)
>          at com.beco.ibeco.app.MainActivity$1.onMenuTabSelected(MainActivity.java:87)
>          at com.beco.ibeco.app.views.bottombar.BottomBar.notifyMenuListener(BottomBar.java:1239)
>          at com.beco.ibeco.app.views.bottombar.BottomBar.updateSelectedTab(BottomBar.java:1199)
>          at com.beco.ibeco.app.views.bottombar.BottomBar.handleClick(BottomBar.java:1161)
>          at com.beco.ibeco.app.views.bottombar.BottomBar.onClick(BottomBar.java:1149)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>   And here is the **code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mActive = true;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initBottomBar(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }  
private void initBottomBar(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.useFixedMode();
        mBottomBar.noTabletGoodness();
        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottombar_menu, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);//line 87

                switch (menuItemId) {

                    case R.id.bottomBarHome:
                        showStoreList();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarMap:
                        showMap();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarDeal:
                        showDeals();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarSettings:
                        showSettings();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarNotification:
                        if (mNotificationBadge != null) {
                            mNotificationBadge.hide();
                            Beco.getApp().clearBadge();
                        }
                        showNotifications();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
                switch (menuItemId) {
                    case R.id.bottomBarHome:
                        if (mCurrentTab != HOME)
                            showStoreList();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarMap:
                        if (mCurrentTab != MAP)
                            showMap();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarDeal:
                        if (mCurrentTab != DEAL)
                            showDeals();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarNotification:
                        if(mCurrentTab != NOTIFICATION) {
                            if (mNotificationBadge != null) {
                                mNotificationBadge.hide();
                                mNotificationBadge.setDealItemCount(0);
                                Beco.getApp().clearBadge();
                            }
                            showNotifications();
                        }
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottomBarSettings:
                        if (mCurrentTab != SETTINGS)
                            showSettings();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        mNotificationBadge = mBottomBar.makeBadgeForTabAt(3, R.color.beco_badge_color, Beco.getApp().getBadgeCount());
    }  
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

How can I override this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popBackStack() after saveInstanceState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474882/popbackstack-after-saveinstancestate)

Answer (score 3):

Create a boolean and check if activity is not going to onpause

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mIsResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mIsResumed = false;
    super.onPause();
}
```

then while loading fragment check

```
if(mIsResumed){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);//line 8
}
```

Comment: Nice clean solution, if you wanted to remove the boolean, you might find lifecycles can help (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html).  Not had chance to play with them but I was hoping that they'd start removing the need for some things like this.

Comment: Yes...But boolean is an easy and simple solution because it will be specific to an activity or class...there are different solutions to check if app goes to onPause while doing fragment transactions..there are complex things like doing registerlife cycle callbacks in the application class too..even that works.